# Initial Commit: "fatal: could not create leading directories of ..."

Tags: git, github, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the initial commit to a git repository on GitHub for a Unity project. I followed along with [this guide](http://www.dannygoodayle.com/2013/02/14/using-unity-with-git/) to get to where I am. Note: For some reason or another, I couldn't set Unity's Asset Serialization Mode to Force Text, so I settled on Mixed (which I believe should work).

When I call git clone --bare . , I get an error.

Note that I am not the creator of the repository and only a contributor (though I am making the initial commit).

Here's everything in my terminal (I'm using Git Bash):

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.4-preview20130916)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

Cheddar@CHEDDAR-PC ~
$ cd Documents/ICS168Swarch/

Cheddar@CHEDDAR-PC ~/Documents/ICS168Swarch
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Users/Cheddar/Documents/ICS168Swarch/.git
/

Cheddar@CHEDDAR-PC ~/Documents/ICS168Swarch (master)
$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Prefabs.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Prefabs/Pellet.prefab.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Prefabs/PelletManager.prefab.meta
.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Prefabs/Player.prefab.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scene1.unity.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts/EatPellets.cs.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts/EatPellets.cs.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts/Movement.cs.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts/Movement.cs.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts/SpawnPellets.cs.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Assets/Scripts/SpawnPellets.cs.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Library/ScriptAssemblies/CompilationComp
leted.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
error: open("Temp/UnityLockfile"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file Temp/UnityLockfile
fatal: adding files failed

Cheddar@CHEDDAR-PC ~/Documents/ICS168Swarch (master)
$ git commit -m "[Initial project setup]"
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore.txt
#       Assembly-CSharp-vs.csproj
#       Assembly-CSharp.csproj
#       Assembly-CSharp.pidb
#       Assets/
#       ICS168Swarch-csharp.sln
#       ICS168Swarch.sln
#       ICS168Swarch.userprefs
#       Library/
#       ProjectSettings/
#       Temp/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Cheddar@CHEDDAR-PC ~/Documents/ICS168Swarch (master)
$ git clone --bare . https://github.com/zarazha/swarch.git
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'https://github.com/zarazha/swarc
h.git'

Cheddar@CHEDDAR-PC ~/Documents/ICS168Swarch (master)
$
```

I searched for solutions to this, but nothing that I found seemed to have the same cause as what I am getting. Help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: zarazha is not your own github account, correct? But you have write permission to the swarch repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though you have two issues here.

First, you need a `.gitignore` file that correctly limits the files you're adding to Git. This is covered in the tutorial you linked, but it seems you've not followed this correctly (as your `add` is including files from the `Temp` folder). Looking at your file list, it seems you've just named this file `.gitignore.txt` by accident. Remove the file extension and then try starting again (re-run the `git add`) and you'll get better results.

The problem with your `clone` is that your second argument (the path `"."`) is incorrect. It's not required (the default would be `.` anyway), and if you do want to specify it, it comes *after* the repository, not before (see [the Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for details - `<repository>` comes before `<directory>`).

So, I think your clone should instead just be this:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/zarazha/swarch.git
```

Comment: That solved the problem. I forgot to get rid of the file extension! Also, I had no idea what the dot after the --bare was for, so I just included it like the tutorial showed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error. Just close unity and you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem one time on MacOS. Turns out SourceTree was trying to clone to my /Developer/Projects folder. This is a system folder turns out. I changed to some other folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Run commands for php-fpm(or your container name) container:

```
docker-compose exec --user=root php-fpm bash
chown www-data:www-data -R /home/www-data
```